# Handle runtime exception in yii2 in rbac

Tags: yii2, rbac

How can I handle rbac exceptions in yii2.
The below function generating an exception while assigning the user a role.

```
  $r = new DbManager;
  $r->init();
  $role = (object) array('name' => $roleName);

if ( $r->assign($role, $userId) ) {
```

The above `$r->assign` generates the exception, such as "Integrity constraint violation". I want to handle all these exceptions. I tried try catch block but no success?

Here is my full code:-

```
$roleName = $this->__checkIfRoleIsValid(\yii::$app->request->post());
        $msg = "The role cannot be changed.";
        $statusCode = 500;
        $success = false;

        if ( !empty($roleName) ) {
            $userId = $this->_getUserId();
            if ( empty($userId) ) {
                \yii::$app->response->statusCode = 500;
                return ['success' => false, 'message' => 'Unauthorize: Invalid x-user-authtoken provided.'];
                \Yii::$app->end();   
            }
            $r = new DbManager;
            $r->init();
            $role = (object) array('name' => $roleName);

            if ( $r->assign($role, $userId) ) {
                $statusCode = 204;
                $msg = "";
                $success = true;
            } 
        }

        \yii::$app->response->statusCode = $statusCode;
        return ['success' => $success, 'message' => $msg];
        \yii::$app->end();
```

Comment: Refer: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: show your full code.

Comment: Updated the code again

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to use `yii\db\Exception` in `catch`.

Try this code.

```
try {

     $r->assign($role, $userId);
     $statusCode = 204;
     $msg = "";
     $success = true;
} catch(yii\db\Exception $e) {
      \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('warning', 'Your message.');
      $success = false;
}
```

Comment: {
name: "PHP Notice"
message: "Undefined offset: 0"
code: 8
type: "yii\base\ErrorException

Comment: give full error message.. and also post error page snap.

Comment: your error is not from DB error that is a offset or array index error. so first check your data..

Comment: If necessary, it's possible to catch _all_ exceptions (`catch (\Exception $e)`).

Comment: `\Exception` is handle only php exception and `yii\db\Exception` is handle DB exception.